# Icons before list item, setting different background

Tags: html, css

Trying to insert icons before list element. I want set different background image to each. Its work when i repeat code for each but i dont want to repeat code.

```
   <li class="circle-list"><a href="#">Option 1</a>
   <li class="circle-list"><a href="#">Option 1</a>
   <li class="circle-list"><a href="#">Option 1</a> 

    li.circle-list:before{
    content: "" ;
    display: inline-block;
    background-size: 19px 19px;
    height:19px;
    width:19px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    vertical-align: sub;
    }

     li.circle-list:nth-child(1):before{ 
     background: url('/images/share-1.svg') no-repeat;

     }
     li.circle-list:nth-child(2):before{
     background: url('/images/share.svg') no-repeat;

     }
```

my question: Why this not working, and how to change background for each list item without repeating code

Comment: It is working for me. In what way is it "Not Working". Also how do you expect to define what background image goes where without defining the background image for each li? CSS sadly can't read your mind :(

Comment: i want only use :

li.circle-list:nth-child(1):before{ 
     background: url('/images/share-1.svg') no-repeat;

for background image
 then nth child 2, 3 and so on,